# When should I fertilize my plants?

Tags: fertilizer

I live in an apartment in Brooklyn that is south facing, and the situation is that I get more light in the winter than the summer because of the amount of trees there are in the backyard (it's very ironic and backwards). Because of that, I've noticed that I get much more plant growth during the winter than I do in the summer since they get less light in the summer.

I saw that you should feed your plants in the spring so they can grow strong but I was wondering whether I should actually feed my plants in the winter since that's when they'll get the most light. Should I feed my plants in fall or in spring?

Comment: I would suggest that you may think they get more light in winter, but it's not true.  Light comes diffused and reflected.  And together with visible light is infra-red, which is definitely stronger in summer.

Comment: @RohitGupta even if there are trees whose leaves block light in the summer and fall off in the winter?